# How to change the contact photo in mountain lion?

Tags: macos, photos.app, contacts

I have iPhoto library in which all my photos exist. I want to pick a photo from iPhoto library and apply it to a contact. But I don't find any such option in new Contacts app (picking a photo form disk). It seems very simple thing to do but yet I cant find a way. Please can you me how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they removed the option to load a picture from disk in the Contacts.app, you can instead drag it from iPhoto or your harddrive into the contact you edit.

Comment: and once you do this you can easily scale and position it within the Contact frame.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to get a photo from your iPhoto library and assign it to a contact, but since neither is invoked from *within* the Contacts app, they are somewhat unintuitive.

1. You can drag a picture from iPhoto (or anywhere, for that matter) onto the photo frame of a contact. Note that, within iPhoto, you can't drag (or copy) a picture while looking at it in the individual, detailed view. But you *can* drag it from the album / event view.
2. You can tag people in your iPhoto photos, attaching names from your Contacts, which will then show up in the Faces library. Once this is done for a given contact, when you edit that contact's photo (in the Contacts app), a Faces option will show up alongside Defaults, Recents, and Camera, from which you can pick iPhoto pictures in which that contact has been tagged.